# Python3 import failure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple directory structure like so:

```
lib/
   dir1/
       __init__.py
       dir2/
           __init__.py
           file1.py
           file2.py
main.py
```

`file1.py` imports `file2.py`

`main.py` does `from dir1.dir2.file1 import *`. However, when I run `main.py` I get the following error:

```
No module named 'file2'
```

When I run `file` from `dir2` it's fine. How does the python3 import system work?

Comment: it's well documentated here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Python 3 imports are *absolute* unless you use explicit relative imports. Use `from . import file2` or use `import dir1.dir2.file2`

Comment: @LaraMaia: that document is way to in-depth and technical to give to someone just new to Python relative and absolute imports.

Comment: Should `main.py` be indented one more level?

Comment: Can you post the entire error message? Its likely that `__init__.py` or `file1.py` is importing file2 and that's where the error is. It should be in the message.

Comment: @tdelaney: From the post: *`file1.py` imports `file2.py`*

Comment: @MartijnPieters - quite right. If OP were to post the traceback we would see the import statement and could offer suggestions. Consider also that `__init__.py` could be importing the file so fixing file1 may not be sufficient.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Ok, it's explained in-depth, but in a very simple way. I do not think this is way to technical. Sometimes it seems that people are lazy to read or afraid of the documentation. I do not feel good about this

Comment: @LaraMaia As someone who has several years of experience in Python, I don't see an answer to the OPs question on the doc page. [PEP 328 (which is linked in the dupe target)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) is much clearer.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters the op question was "How does the python3 import system work?" and not "how do I solve this problem". You need to read better.